# Validate existing email in flutter using a api rest

Tags: mongodb, rest, api, flutter, dart

I have a signup screen in my app. I am also using a api rest to connect to database (mongodb).  I am making This api in nodejs. In this api, the email is set unique.

How can I make the flutter show to the user, if he enters with an existing email on database, that the email already exists?

Thank you in advance ;)

Comment: you need to have a backend side logic to check if the email exists in the database and if the email exists you you should give a response as email exists and if not signup successful @afifi has mentioned it.

Answer (score 0):

```
type this code in your onPressed method:    

 

    http.Response response = await http.post(
                                  '//type your server-url here',
                                  headers: <String, String>{
                                    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
                                  },
                                  body: jsonEncode(<String, String>{
                                    'name': name,
                                    'email': email,
                                    'password': password,
                                  }),
                                );
        
                                if (response.body == 'email already exists') {

//the message "email already exists" comes from your backend.
//It may differ from this message depending on your backend

                                  Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
                                      SnackBar(content: Text('Email already exists')));
                                } else {
                                  Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
                                      SnackBar(content: Text('Processing Data')));
                                }
```